# What is the efficient way to pass objects and/or list of objects between activities?

Tags: java, android, json, design-patterns

I am new to android and learning good design patters in one of my classes. I am developing an app as part of my project but I am running into some design problems and trying to figure out what is a good pattern to follow.

I have the following classes

```
public class Playlist {
  ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
  //..getters and setters and song to list

  }

public class Song {
  private String name;
  private String artist;
  private String File;
  //Getters and setters

}
```

Throughout the app I will have an ArrayList of all the created playlist and
an ArrayList of all the songs available.

The app eventually will download a JSON object and make an instance of a Song class for that object.

I have been looking into way to keep the list of playlist objects and list of song objects available through all the activities and I have found the following solutions:

1. making a Gson and saving it to sharedPref file (this does not seem like a good idea since I will be saving and writing constantly.)
2. I have also read about using sqllite. But I don't see the point of it since I will be getting most songs as a JSON object and making a song instance with that object.
3. I implemented playlist as parceable to be able to pass the list through an intent but this does not seem like the best way since I will have to update the shared pref every time there is a change.

Can anyone point me in the right direction which way to follow or if making a singleton for the lists seem like the most efficient way. (Global singletons so android wouldn't destroy the objects onDestroy())

Thanks

Comment: You could also look at implementing Fragments instead of Activities for the different screens. You could then implement callbacks back to the activity from the fragment to manage the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **SQLite** would be the correct approach as soon as you want to *store the data across launches*, but if you just want to keep data while your app is active it is unfitting.
- You can use a **global Singleton** and it is certainly the *easiest solution*.
- An alternative might be an **Eventbus** system: each comonent stores a copy of the data. One component is responsible for updating the data. If an update is available it notifies all other components through the Eventbus. This is probably the *nicest solution considering design patterns*.

Comment: I am just wondering if the SQLite approach would be a little redundant since a user eventually will download a "song" (in a JSON object) so this will result in download object -> make it an instance of song -> added it to the Arraylist of songs -> Add it to SQLite. Is this a good approach? Thanks

Comment: If you need to store data you have to introduce a persitent representation. If your data is a list, a database is most of the time the correct choice. Depending on your usage it might be a better idea to go download → sqlite → pojo, but generally what you said is a good.

Comment: Interesting. Just wondering something about the way you mentioned. During the app cycle is the app is destroyed it would still more beneficial to let the objects get destroyed and query the database and make the new objects when the app is opened again? ie: starting app , on create, check db, make the list, present to the view.

Comment: correct. Your java model should always be just a presentation of the data in the database. Updates to the java content *must* be also made in the database to ensure consistency. That's why it is sometimes a good idea to treat the java representation as final, make changes in the database and then requery the representation.

Comment: nice. Thanks a lot for the answer and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1. To pass objects between activities, `Parcelable` is a good idea.

With `my_object`, an object of a class that implements `Parcelable` :

To pass between activities, just use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA, ActivityB);
intent.putExtra("MY_OBJECT", my_object);
...
```

Also, use this to make your class parcelable :
http://www.parcelabler.com/

2. Now, if you want to keep your list of music, you should use internal database sqlite, and store each object as a row of the Sqlite Tab. You can then implement method that will return the complete list of songs that is in your internal database.